# How do I install librsvg 2.36 on Lucid?

Tags: 10.04, svg

As I believe, latest `librsvg` for `Lucid`(that is 2.26.3) seems to have a bug in that it shifts the layers of the image.

I tried to build it from source but then I had to build dependencies, and they also have dependencies... Is there an easier way to install 2.36?

I'm a newbie in linux, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @CharlieS I built it from source following the instructions on http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/librsvg.html. Quite long and painful. Unfortunately, I didn't make a package :( We have upgraded to 12.04 since then.

Comment: We're in the process of upgrading to 12.04 to get this package now :)